# Thread deadlock avoidance

Tags: java, multithreading

I want to know if it's authorized to avoid Thread deadlocks by making the threads not starting at the same time? Is there an other way to avoid the deadlocks in the following code?

Thanks in advance!

```
public class ThreadDeadlocks {

    public static Object Lock1 = new Object();
    public static Object Lock2 = new Object();

    public static void main(String args[]) {

        ThreadDemo1 t1 = new ThreadDemo1();
        ThreadDemo2 t2 = new ThreadDemo2();

        t1.start();
        try {
            Thread.sleep(100);
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
        }
        t2.start();
    }

    private static class ThreadDemo1 extends Thread {
        public void run() {
            synchronized (Lock1) {
                System.out.println("Thread 1: Holding lock 1...");
                try {
                    Thread.sleep(10);
                } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                }
                System.out.println("Thread 1: Waiting for lock 2...");
                synchronized (Lock2) {
                    System.out.println("Thread 1: Holding lock 1 & 2...");
                }
            }
        }
    }

    private static class ThreadDemo2 extends Thread {
        public void run() {
            synchronized (Lock2) {
                System.out.println("Thread 2: Holding lock 2...");
                try {
                    Thread.sleep(10);
                } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                }
                System.out.println("Thread 2: Waiting for lock 1...");
                synchronized (Lock1) {
                    System.out.println("Thread 2: Holding lock 1 & 2...");
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: As a rule of thumb, `sleep()` can never _fix_ a concurrency problem.  What it can do is, it can make the problem much less likely to occur.  That's OK for demos, learning, and personal use; but if you're building production software what it translates to is, it turns a bug that would have been caught in testing into a bug that won't happen until months or years later, at a customer site, and which, by then, will be almost impossible to diagnose.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, starting threads at different times is not a way to avoid deadlocks - in fact, what you'd be trying with different start times is a heuristic to serialize their critical sections. ++ see why at the and of this answer

[Edited with a solution]

> Is there an other way to avoid the deadlocks in the following code?

The simplest way is to acquire the locks in the same order *on both threads*

```
synchronized(Lock1) {
   // do some work
  synchronized(Lock2) {
     // do some other work and commit (make changes visible)
  }
}
```

If the logic of your code dictates you can't do that, then use `java.util.concurrent.locks` classes. For example

```
ReentrantLock Lock1=new ReentrantLock();
ReentrantLock Lock2=new ReentrantLock();

private static class ThreadDemo1 extends Thread {
    public void run() {
         while(true) {
            Lock1.lock(); // will block until available
            System.out.println("Thread 1: Holding lock 1...");
            try {
                // Do some preliminary work here, but do not "commit" yet
                Thread.sleep(10);
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            }
            System.out.println("Thread 1: Waiting for lock 2...");
            if(!Lock2.tryLock(30, TimeUnit.MILLISECOND)) {
               System.out.println("Thread 1: not getting a hold on lock 2...");

               // altruistic behaviour: if I can't do it, let others 
               // do their work with Lock1, I'll try later
               System.out.println("Thread 1: release lock 1 and wait a bit");
               Lock1.unlock();
               Thread.sleep(30);
               System.out.println("Thread 1: Discarding the work done before, will retry getting lock 1");

            }
            else {
               System.out.println("Thread 1: got a hold on lock 2...");
               break;
            }
        }
        // if we got here, we know we are holding both locks
        System.out.println("Thread 1: both locks available, complete the work");
        // work...
        Lock2.unlock(); // release the locks in the reverse... 
        Lock1.unlock(); // ... order of acquisition

    }
}

// do the same for the second thread
```

---

++ To demonstrate why delays in starting the threads at different times is not a foolproof solution, think if you can afford to delay one of the threads by 10 seconds in the example below. Then think what will you do *if you don't actually know how long to wait*.

```
private static class ThreadDemo1 extends Thread {
    public void run() {
        synchronized (Lock1) {
            System.out.println("Thread 1: Holding lock 1...");
            try {
                // modelling a workload here: 
                // can take anywhere up to 10 seconds
                Thread.sleep((long)(Math.random()*10000));
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            }
            System.out.println("Thread 1: Waiting for lock 2...");
            synchronized (Lock2) {
                System.out.println("Thread 1: Holding lock 1 & 2...");
            }
        }
    }
}

private static class ThreadDemo2 extends Thread {
    public void run() {
        synchronized (Lock2) {
            System.out.println("Thread 2: Holding lock 2...");
            try {
                // modelling a workload here: 
                // can take anywhere up to 10 seconds
                Thread.sleep((long)(Math.random()*10000));
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            }
            System.out.println("Thread 2: Waiting for lock 1...");
            synchronized (Lock1) {
                System.out.println("Thread 2: Holding lock 1 & 2...");
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: How can I modify the run methods on both ThreadDemo classes to avoid deadlocks?

Comment: I've tried to acquire the locks in the same order and it works, thanks, but I want to understand how does it works?

Comment: @peter59 - why does it work? Simple, if you forget the second lock and look only at the first, whichever thread acquires it can do the work, others will wait. Now, since doing the work requires the second lock and, *if you require both locks, the second lock cannot be acquired without holding the first* it follows that whichever thread will acquire the first lock will have no *dead-lock problems* acquiring the second one (even though it may have to wait for threads which do acquire the second lock *only*).

Answer (score 2):

There are two ways to get a deadlock:

1. Lock escalation.  For example, a thread holding a shareable read
   lock tries to escalate to an exclusive write lock.  If more than one
   thread holding a read lock tries to escalate to a write lock, a
   deadlock results.  This doesn't apply to what you're doing.  (Offhand, I don't even know if it's *possible* to escalate a lock in Java.)
2. Unspecified lock order.  If thread A locks object 1, then tries to lock object 2, while thread B locks object 2 then tries to lock object 1, a deadlock can result.  This is exactly what you're doing.

Those are the only ways to get a deadlock.  Every deadlock scenario will come down to one of those.

If you don't want deadlocks, don't do either of those.  Never escalate a lock, and always specify lock order.

Those are the only ways to prevent deadlocks.  Monkeying around with thread timing by delaying things is not guaranteed to work.

Comment: If I didn't put the delay between the 2 threads, I have a thread deadlock like this: Thread 1: Holding lock 1...
Thread 2: Holding lock 2...
Thread 2: Waiting for lock 1...
Thread 1: Waiting for lock 2... So, should I modify the run methods of both ThreadDemo classes or can I leave the delay between the 2 starts of these threads on the main?

Comment: @peter59 Any delay is not guaranteed to work.  The *only* guaranteed way to avoid a deadlock in the absence of lock escalation is to always obtain locks in the same order.  It's *that* simple.

Comment: So, how should I do for always obtain locks in the same order?

Answer (score 1):

As the other mentioned, delays won't help because threads by their nature have unknown start time. When you call start() on a thread, it becomes runnable, but you cannot know when it will be running.

Answer (score 1):

I'm assuming this is just demo code, so you already know that playing with sleeps is not guaranteed to work (as stressed in other answers).

In your demo code I see two options to try avoid the deadlock:

- Remove any sleep within the body of the functions executed by the threads and just put a single, long enough, sleep between the start of the two threads; in practical terms, this should give enough time to the first thread to be scheduled and complete its work, then the second thread will acquire both locks without contention. But, you already know, scheduling policies are not under your control and this is not guaranteed to work at all.
- Do acquire locks in the same order in both threads, without using any sleep at all, i.e.

  ```
   synchronized (Lock1) {
      synchronized (Lock2) {
         // ...
      }
   }
  ```

  This is guaranteed to remove any possible deadlock, because the first thread to acquire `Lock1` will gain the possibility to complete its work while blocking the other thread until completion.

UPDATE:

To understand why acquiring locks in the same order is the only guaranteed way to avoid deadlock, you should recall what's the whole purpose of locks.

A thread is said to own a lock between the time it has acquired the lock and released the lock. As long as a thread owns a lock, no other thread can acquire the same lock. In fact, the other thread will block when it attempts to acquire the same lock.

Every object in Java has an intrinsic lock associated with it. The synchronized statement let you automatically acquire the intrinsic lock of the specified object and release it after code execution.

Comment: I've tried your second option and it works, thanks, but I don't understand why the first thread is blocking the second during its completion?

Comment: Okay thank you very much for your explanation, so it's all thanks to the synchronized statement right?